# Closed-form solution to this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm getting stuck at solving the following ODE:

$\ddot{f}(x)-\dfrac{\dot{f}(x)^2}{f(x)}+C\left(\dfrac{\dot{f}(x)}{f(x)}\right)^2=0$, where $C\neq 0$ constant, and let $f(0)=P$, $\dot{f}(0)=Q$.

Is it possible to find a closed-form solution to this problem? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the trick is to work with $x(y)$ and to use the fact that $$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}=-\frac{\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}}{\left({\frac{dy}{dx}}\right)^3}$$  So, replacing $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ by its expression as functions of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ and $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ leads to somethink looking like $$-\frac {x''}{x'}-\frac 1 y+\frac{C}{y^2}=0$$ which can be simplified using $p=x'$; this leads to $$\log(p)=-\frac{C}{y}-\log (y)+K$$ that is to say $$x'=\frac{K}y\,e^{-\frac C y}$$ Now, using, from definition, the exponential integral function, we then have $$x=a+b\, \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{C}{y}\right)$$ $$x'=-\frac{b e^{-\frac{C}{y}}}{y}$$

I let you finding $a,b$ from the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Maple finds the implicit solution
$$ {\it Ei} \left( 1,{\frac {C}{f \left( x \right) }} \right) -{\frac {Qx
}{P}{{\rm e}^{-{ {C}/{P}}}}}-{\it Ei} \left( 1,{\frac {C}{P}}
 \right) =0
$$